# How to calculate RMSE by hand for decision tree output?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, data-mining, decision-tree

Suppose we have a decision tree output from python that looks like this:

[Sample Decision Tree Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fZxi.png)

Suppose we are interested in predicting the class 1 of the target variable (aka the predicted event probability is the Prob (class = 1)). How do we calculate the Root Average Squared Error by hand?

Comment: RMSE is only for regression and not for classification.

Comment: I think this question needs further discussion, for which stats.stackexchange.com is suitable. That said, I have a couple of comments. Instead of RMSE, look at cross entropy, which is the goodness of fit appropriate for classifiers. Cross entropy needs class probability outputs, which you can estimate as (number of positive examples)/(total number of examples) per leaf of the tree. Good luck and have fun.